# Flagging if consecutive rows in a column have same value in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
ID  Flag
1000    0
1000    1
1000    1
1000    1
1000    1
1000    0
2000    0
2000    1
2000    0
2000    1
2000    0
```

I want to add a column that flags an ID if they have at least 3 consecutive "1" in the "Flag" columnin SQL Server.

Comment: what is your expected output here?

Comment: Is there a field for the actual sequence ?

Comment: Is there more data in the table? Based on the data you've shown, there's no way to order the data to determine which records are consecutive.

Comment: SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  There is no such thing as "consecutive" values, unless another column provides the ordering information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may help. It seems similar to what you are asking and may get you onto the right track.
[Find records with 3 or more consecutive records with same value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31643682/find-records-with-3-or-more-consecutive-records-with-same-value)

So something similar to this maybe

```
CREATE TABLE Table1 (
id int,
flag bit)

INSERT into Table1 (id,flag)
VALUES (1000,0),(1000,1),(1000,1),(1000,1)


SELECT t.*
FROM (SELECT t.*, count(*) over (partition by ID) as cnt
  FROM (SELECT table1.*,
               (row_number() over (partition by id order by flag) 

               ) as grp
        from table1
       ) t
  WHERE flag = 1
 ) t
WHERE cnt >= 3;
```