# Find customers with at least 5 transactions in At most 3 consecutive days

Tags: sql, sql-server, count, days

I have a table in SQL Server that contains customers' transactions From 2022-02-10 to 2022-03-10.

I want to find customers that have at least 5 transactions on At most three consecutive days

For example, output of below table should be `CustomerId = 2 and customerid=3`

| Id | CustomerId | Transactiondate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2022-03-01 |
| 2 | 1 | 2022_03_01 |
| 3 | 1 | 2022_03_05 |
| 4 | 1 | 2022_03_07 |
| 5 | 1 | 2022_03_07 |
| 6 | 2 | 2022_03_05 |
| 7 | 2 | 2022_03_05 |
| 8 | 2 | 2022_03_06 |
| 9 | 2 | 2022_03_06 |
| 10 | 2 | 2022_03_07 |
| 1 | 3 | 2022-03-01 |
| 2 | 3 | 2022_03_01 |
| 3 | 3 | 2022_03_01 |
| 4 | 3 | 2022_03_03 |
| 5 | 3 | 2022_03_03 |

I tried this query but it doesn't have good performance for a large table:

```
select distinct p1.customerid
from trntbl p1
join trntbl p2 on p2.id <> p1.id
               and p2.customerid = p1.customerid
               and p2.TransactionDate >= p1.TransactionDate
               and p2.TransactionDate < date_add(day, 3, p1.prchasedate)
group by p1.customerid, p1.id
having count(*) >= 4
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31643682/find-records-with-3-or-more-consecutive-records-with-same-value

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3743508/tsql-finding-order-that-occurred-in-3-consecutive-months

Comment: @marc_s I add it

Answer (score 2):

If customers must have done transactions in three consecutive days (meaning that 5 transactions in a day then nothing in the next two days wouldn't count), then this can be done with two self joins:

```
with cte as
(select CustomerId, Transactiondate, count(*) ct
from table_name
group by CustomerId, Transactiondate)
select distinct t1.CustomerId
from cte t1  inner join cte t2
on t1.Transactiondate = dateadd(day, 1, t2.Transactiondate)
and t1.CustomerId = t2.CustomerId
inner join cte t3
on t2.Transactiondate = dateadd(day, 1, t3.Transactiondate)
and t3.CustomerId = t2.CustomerId
;
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=02ad592fdc160c5ddcd793265455683f)

Answer (score 1):

This is actually a *gaps and islands* problem, you can solve by using analytic window functions to subtract sequential *row_number* from consecutive days and then grouping, after first "plugging" any gaps with the help of a numbers table.

```
with numbers as (select top(20) Row_Number() over(order by (select null))-1 n from master.dbo.spt_values),
dRanges as (
  select customerId,
        Min(Transactiondate) CustStartDate, 
        Max(Transactiondate) CustEndDate 
  from t
  group by CustomerId
), dates as (
    select * 
    from dranges r
    outer apply (
        select DateAdd(day,n,r.CustStartDate) SeqDate
        from numbers n
        where DateAdd(day,n,r.CustStartDate) < = r.CustEndDate 
    )d
), q as (
    select customerId, transactiondate, Count(*) qty
    from t
    group by CustomerId, Transactiondate
), g as (
    select d.CustomerId, d.SeqDate, IsNull(q.qty,0)Qty, 
      DateAdd(day, - row_number() over (partition by d.customerid order by d.SeqDate), d.SeqDate) as dGrp
    from dates d
    left join q on q.Transactiondate = d.SeqDate and q.CustomerId = d.CustomerId
)
select customerId
from g
group by CustomerId, dGrp
having Count(*) <= 3 and Sum(qty) >= 5
```

[DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=4922d2f896ba32ef2e4d6330f1b51b75)

Comment: i Think having count(*)<=3  is correct

Comment: How did you arrive at that conclusion? The requirement is at least 3, not at most.

Comment: i correct the question

Comment: Oh, well if you're going to change the requirements then of course! The basic solution though is the same.

Comment: thank you very much... i test your query with a customer that has 5 transaction in 3 diffrent dates but not in 3 day consecutive...the query doesnt work....can you help me?

Comment: That sounds like Customer1 in your sample data. Can you modify the example Fiddle to demonstrate?

Comment: i eddited m question and add new data , with this new data customerid=3 must be shown but it wont

Comment: @a_se Using your additional data it [works fine](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=8413b0ba407f738f7e577e699e0c3662) as you can see, CustomerId 2 and 3 are returned, both meeting the requirement.

Comment: you didnt enter data same as the example i consider in the question ,check  the  last one left

Comment: Ah yes that was my bad I must have made a typo copying it out. will revisit.

Comment: @a_se I had another play around and have revised the query above - it's not the most elegant solution but I think it works, no doubt room for improvement, let me know if this now works for you?

Answer (score 1):

Although this is a gaps-and-islands problem, there are shortcuts you can take.

You can group it up by date, then get the row 2 previous, and filter by only rows where the 2 previous row is exactly two days apart.

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT
  CustomerId
FROM (
    SELECT
      t.CustomerId,
      v.Date,
      Prev2 = LAG(v.Date, 2) OVER (PARTITION BY t.CustomerId ORDER BY v.Date)
    FROM YourTable t
    CROSS APPLY (VALUES( CAST(Transactiondate AS date) )) v(Date)
    GROUP BY
      t.CustomerId,
      v.Date
) t
WHERE DATEDIFF(day, t.Prev2, t.Date) = 2
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=dc8d26740a305405b2776fc958a5e664)

If the base table only has a maximum of one row per date then you can forgo the `GROUP BY`.

Answer (score 0):

You could make use of datediff function and verify if the sum of the date differences are between 3 and 5 (provided the max of the differences is just 1) since the dates might be unique (for example customerid 2 can have transaction dates as 5,6,7,8,9 of March 2022) and this should be taken into account too.

```
declare @tbl table(id int identity,customerid int,transactiondate date)

insert into @tbl(customerid,transactiondate)
values(1,'2022-03-01')
,(1,'2022-03-01')
,(1,'2022-03-05')
,(1,'2022-03-07')
,(1,'2022-03-07')
,(2,'2022-03-05')
,(2,'2022-03-05')
,(2,'2022-03-06')
,(2,'2022-03-06')
,(2,'2022-03-07')

select customerid from (
select *
,SUM(datediff)over(partition by customerid order by transactiondate)[sum]
,max(datediff)over(partition by customerid order by transactiondate)[max]
from( 
select customerid , transactiondate,
DATEDIFF(DAY
, 
case when LEAD(transactiondate,1)over(partition by customerid order by transactiondate) 
is null then 
LAG(transactiondate,1,transactiondate)
over(partition by customerid order by transactiondate)
else
transactiondate end

, case when LEAD(transactiondate,1)over(partition by customerid order by transactiondate) 
is null then 
transactiondate
else
LEAD(transactiondate,1,transactiondate)
over(partition by customerid order by transactiondate)end) as [datediff]
,ROW_NUMBER()over(partition by customerid order by transactiondate)rownum
from @tbl
)t
)t1
where t1.rownum = 5
and t1.max = 1
and t1.sum between 3 and 5
```